# Populating std::map and calling find return end() even though the entry is in the map

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, stdmap

So, I create this map on the fly so I can update the image type for all the images in the library (currently over 1 million).  The map populates well, HOWEVER, despite visually seeing the extension (`"jpg"`) added to the map, `std::map::find("jpg") == std::map::end()` always.  What gives.

```
void CImageLibrary::ThreadedUpdateImageLibraryFileDuringOpen(shared_ptr<ScanData> pScanData)
{
    size_t nCount = pScanData->GetImageLibrary()->m_imageEntries.count();
    std::map<std::wstring, CImageType *> mapImageExtToType;
    for (const auto &pImageType : pScanData->GetImageLibrary()->m_vecImageTypes)
    {
        std::vector<std::wstring> vecExtensions;
        pImageType->GetAssociatedExtensions(vecExtensions);
        for (auto ext : vecExtensions)
        {
            std::transform(ext.begin(), ext.end(), ext.begin(), ::tolower);
            mapImageExtToType[ext] = pImageType;
        }
    }

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < nCount; ++idx)
    {
        CImageEntry *pEntry = pScanData->GetImageLibrary()->m_imageEntries[idx];
        if (pEntry && !pEntry->GetImageType())
        {
            wstring &wsPath = pEntry->GetPathName(), wsExt;
            size_t nIdx = wsPath.find_last_of('.');
            wsExt = wsPath.substr(nIdx + 1);
            std::transform(wsExt.begin(), wsExt.end(), wsExt.begin(), ::tolower);

            auto Itor = mapImageExtToType.find(wsExt);
            if (Itor == mapImageExtToType.end())
                pEntry->m_pImageType = nullptr;
            else
                pEntry->m_pImageType = Itor->second;
        }
    }
    pScanData->GetBkgndThreadManager()->MarkOperationThreadDone(std::this_thread::get_id());
}
```

Comment: There are currently 21 entries in the map

Comment: The code looks fine to me. But without seeing how `m_imageEntries` and `m_vecImageTypes` are populated, it is hard to diagnose why it doesn't work for you. Have you tried printing out what is actually stored in `mapImageExtToType` and `wsExt` when `find()` fails?

Comment: This code in itself is not enough to work out the problem I am afraid. Work through @RemyLebeau questions / suggestions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, printed no.  But a breakpoint set there seems fine.  I see the same wstring value as a key in mapImageExttoType as in wsExt

Comment: @user9778277 does this simpler example work for you? `std::map<std::wstring, CImageType *> mapImageExtToType; std::wstring wsExt = L"jpg"; mapImageExtToType[wsExt] = ...; auto Itor = mapImageExtToType.find(wsExt);` If `Itor` is not `mapImageExtToType.end()` then the problem is somewhere in your code logic.